# Importing reviews for magento 1.9.x from aliexpres & amazon

Tags: magento-1.9

I am wondering is there a company out there that provides a plugin for importing reviews from amazon,aliexpress and different websites with few clicks?

I am running Magento version 1.9.x

thank you for your help

Comment: i forgot to add also the reviews plugin should have an option of image adding by customers and ofcourse importing  a plugin which i like personaly is a shopify plugin which has a really nice look  and supports all futures i nead but they dont support magento ...  https://apps.shopify.com/ali-reviews?surface_detail=reviews&surface_inter_position=1&surface_intra_position=6&surface_type=search

https://ali-reviews-fireapps.myshopify.com/products/men-bracelets-natural-healing

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Aliexpress Magento Importer, you can easily import Aliexpress products into your Magento store to sell the products and earn handsome revenue.

- It helps you to import products from Aliexpress.com into your Magento store.
- User Friendly and easy to understand.
- Imports Simple and Configurable Products from the Aliexpress store to the Magento store through this extension.

You can refer to this extension: https://cedcommerce.com/magento-extensions/aliexpress-magento-importer or https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Dropship.html